# Loading of mechanical drawing

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to load some 3D mechanical drawing in ROS? I mean .step or similar files.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110716/loading-of-mechanical-drawing/) by [Karel](https://answers.ros.org/users/9976/karel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-16**:
Load to where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, if you want to visualize them on rviz (ROS 3D viewer), this tread can help:
http://answers.ros.org/question/10177/query-on-urdfxacro-file/

This can help too:
http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter

---

Originally posted by [David Galdeano](https://answers.ros.org/users/9481/david-galdeano/) with karma: 357 on 2013-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1